# Como criar uma função em C que pesquise por palavras em arquivos txt em um diretório predefinido?

Tags: c

```
void pesquisarexerword()
{

    DIR *dir;
    char *strdir, *strget,  t, *str;
    struct dirent *lsdir, *dirarq;
    FILE *arq;


    do{
        printf("\n Digite o Diretorio que Deseja Fazer a Pesquisa:\n");
        system("pause");
        fflush(stdin);//se desejar pesquisar outro diretotio ele volta aki
        gets(strdir);
        dir = opendir(strdir);//abrir o diretorio

        if( dir == NULL)
        {
        printf("\n\t****ERROR DIR NAO EXISTE*****"); return;
        }
        printf("\n Palavra que deseja Pesquisar:");
        gets(str);

        system("cls");

        do
        {
            dirarq = readdir(dir);//retorna o dir listando do arq
            arq = fopen(dirarq->d_name,"r");//abrir um arquivo no diretorio
            do
            {
                fgets(strget,244,arq);


                if(strcmp(str,strtok(strget,"")) == 0)//teste para achara a palavar no arquivo
                {
                printf("\n Nome do Arquivo Desejado:\n");
                printf("\n %s",dirarq->d_name);
               }

            }while(!feof(arq) || strcmp(str,strtok(strget,"")) != 0 );//teste se ha a frase dentro do arquivo ate acabar o arq

        }while( dir != NULL);//testa todo os arq do dir mencionado
        system("cls");

    printf("\n Deseja Pesquisar em outro Diretorio(Y/N)?:");
    scanf(" %c", &t);
    toupper(t);
    }while( t != 'N');

}
```

Comment: Qual o seu problema?

Comment: preciso que o usuario digite um diretorio para pesquisar nele uma ou duas (em outro codigo) palavras e assim exibir os arquivos do diretorio que tenham essas palavras..!

Comment: tenho outro codigo que ele ultiliza duas palavras mas os testes de paradas e os parametros para a STRTOK() ficam bugadas

Comment: Não perguntei qual era a tarefa como um todo, mas qual o problema específico que te impede na conclusão dessa tarefa. Se não me expressei bem antes, agora espero ter sido direto ao ponto

Comment: se resume  no terceiro loop e o parametro para strtok(), pois se passo a string lida do arq para strtok() como que fica a mesma no loop?

Comment: esse problema nao consegui resolver...

Answer (score 0):

Precisas chamar o strtok a primeira vez antes de entrar no terceiro loop.

```
token = strtok(strget, "");
```

Dentro do terceiro loop, deves chamar passando NULL como parâmetro:

```
token = strtok(NULL, "");
```